# Maximizing the mutual information related to minimizing KL divergence?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, kullback-leibler, mutual-information

Let's say we are drawing two random variables from two distributions, like x~p and z~q,
then maximizing mutual information I(x;z) leads to decreasing KL divergence D_kl(p|q) ?

This sounds correct to me intuitively! but I cannot show this, or find anything in literature about it. So maybe I am missing something here. Can you tell me why this could be wrong? thanks.

Comment: If you write out the mathematical expressions for the two, it should be clear that they are not the same, nor are they monotonic transforms of each other.  Consequently, maximizing MI does not always decrease KL divergence.

Comment: yes. But I am not saying they are equal. I am saying decreasing D_kl(p|q) should increase I(x;z) when x~p and z~q. It would be helpful if you can give me an example of case that this is not true?

Comment: I'm not saying they are equal either :)  If they aren't monotonic transforms of each other, then there are locations on the MI vs $D_{kl}$ curve where they are both increasing (or decreasing), and other locations where one is increasing and the other is decreasing, which implies directly that you can sometimes increase MI and not decrease $D_{kl}$